# Assign new value via tuple destructuring

Tags: rust

My simplified code:

```
fn f() -> (u32, u32) {
    (5, 5)
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 6_u32;
    let mut j = 6_u32;

    // some condition
    if true {
        let (new_i, new_j) = f();
        i = new_i;
        j = new_j;
    }

    // code that use i and j
}
```

Is it possible to simplify the code:

```
let (new_i, new_j) = f();
i = new_i;
j = new_j;
```

In my real code, I pass 4 values in the tuple.